# How to summon a mob with an effect

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to `/summon` a tamed wolf, or any other mob, with one or more effect(s)?

Comment: Heyheyhey, why -2 rating after I post this question? Is there anything idiot I wrote?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: These are two different questions that are best asked as separate questions.

Comment: Since question a derives from question b, I'm going to be more helpful and simply remove question b, rather than vote to close. IF applicable after it is answered, post your second question as a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in order to tame a wolf you have to to become the `owner`. After it is tame it will take on this status.  to summon an owned wolf we will have to open chat by pressing `T`.  Then type or paste this command `/summon Wolf ~ ~ ~ {Owner:PlayerName}`  Replace (PlayerName) with your Minecraft name.

As for summoning mobs with effects and attributes.  There is so much you can do and the possibilities are endless, but for a basic overview I would watch this video `by dragnoz`

Note: He did do this video in Minecraft 1.7 so some info might be outdated.

Comment: This youtuber don't show separately how to give the mob an effect when summoning, and it makes my mind confuse.

Comment: Sorry about this but I think that I will just delete my question.

Comment: Oh no finally the video was helpful; it just that I couldn't put the song on ON, so I didn't understood what he said. Now I can and now I understand. Thank :)